# Arithmetic mean sequence of a convergent complex sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a complex sequence.
Let $\sigma_n = (\sum_{i=0}^n s_i)$/$(n+1)$.

Say $s_n → s$.

I have tried and i could only show that $|\sigma_n| →|s|$.

How do i show that $\sigma_n →s$?

I have searched for it and some solutions use "inequality of complex number", but as you know order relation cannot be defined in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Brian It's a typo. Dividing by n+1 is what i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $N=N_\varepsilon$ such that $$|s_n-s|<\varepsilon$$ for $n>N$, and note that 
   $$|\sigma_n - s|=\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n (s_k-s)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n |s_k-s|\tag{1}$$
2. Break up the sum in (1) at $k=N$.
3. Use the max esitmate on the first terms and the $\varepsilon$-estimate on the tail.

Do you see how to complete the proof?

---

A sequence $s_n$ for which $\sigma_n$ converges is called [Cesàro-summable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), the result is that convergence implies Cesàro-summable.

Comment: I'm not really good in LaTeX. There's "Math Processing Error" after "Note that" on my phone.. It's awkward but would you please simplify that?

Comment: $|\sigma_n - s|=\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n (s_k-s)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n |s_k-s|\tag{1}$

Comment: Maybe the tag "(1)" is the problem? Can you read this..? $$|\sigma_n - s|=\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n (s_k-s)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_0^n |s_k-s|$$

Comment: Yes, i got it thank you :)