# How to show that $\lim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}=0 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

Show that 
$$\lim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =0 $$

I've proved that this sequence converges (it is bounded and decreasing). NOW, I need to find a sequence that is bigger than this one and goes to zero. Maybe something using geometric serie of 1/2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=\ln(n)+\gamma+\alpha_n$, where $\alpha_n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What have you tried? You can in fact prove that you couldn't do what you want with a geometric series. Anyway, hint: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} < \log(n)+1$$

Comment: @user121270: You mean $\alpha_n \to 0$.

Comment: See also some older posts, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409369/harmonic-number-divided-by-n, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739375/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-h-n-n-0-h-n-is-the-n-th-harmonic-number-u, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/find-lim-n-to-infty-1-frac12-frac1n-frac1n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can approximate a finite sum with a definite integral (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Approximation_by_definite_integrals)). We obtain that
$$
\log(n+1)=\int_1^{n+1}x^{-1}\mathrm dx\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i\le1+\int_1^nx^{-1}\mathrm dx=1+\log n.
$$
Now we need to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}n=0.
$$
This can be done by using l'Hôpital's rule (a more general statement is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712613/prove-that-all-values-satisfy-this-expression/712618)).

Comment: What is the reason to downvote my answer?

Answer (score 24):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} = \sum_{1\le i\le\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{i} + \sum_{\sqrt{n}<i\le n} \frac{1}{i} \le \sum_{1\le i\le\sqrt{n}} 1 + \sum_{\sqrt{n}<i\le n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n} = 2\sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: i need some help. how do you establish the inequality: $$\sum_{\sqrt{n}<i \le n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le \sqrt{n} $$ ? do you mind explaining to me?

Comment: @karhas This is the sum of a constant.  Just multiply by the number of terms.

Answer (score 3):

In the same direction as user121270 and  coolydudey60 in their comments $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =\frac{H_n}{n}$$ and for large values of $n$ $$\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{\gamma +\log \left(n\right)}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{12
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$ and then what V.C. proposed in his answer $\frac{1+\log(n)}{n}$ seems to be very good.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](http://www.google.com/search?q=Stolz+Cesaro) we get
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i}n = 
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{(n+1)-n} = 
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n+1} =
0.$$

You can consider this as a special case of a more general fact that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$, then also
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n=L.$$
(If a sequence is convergent, then the arithmetic means of the first $n$ element converge to the same limit.)

See for example this question (and other questions shown there among linked questions):
[Prove convergence of the sequence $(z_1+z_2+\cdots + z_n)/n$ of Cesaro means](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means)

Answer (score 2):

I just write an alternate approach, which may be useful:

Consider $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=\ln(a_n)$ then:
$$1\leq a_n=[e^{\frac{1}{1}}e^{\frac{1}{2}}...e^{\frac{1}{n}}]^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{e^{\frac{1}{1}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}}+...+e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$, the right-hand-side go to $1$ as $n$ approach $\infty$ (Cesaro mean), then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=1$, which implies your limit is $\ln(1)=0$.

Comment: The justifying of the $e^{1/n}$ sum using Cesàro means is overkill. The question is exactly equivalent to the Cesàro mean of $1/n$ in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With Stolz-Cesaro Theorem:

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over n}\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}{1 \over i}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n + 1}1/i - \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}1/i \over \pars{n + 1} - n}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1/\pars{n + 1} \over 1}=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over n + 1}= \color{#66f}{\large 0}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to prove that a Harmonic series is $O(\log n)$ and the result follows immediately

Answer (score 0):

Another more general way is the following theorem:
Let's $a_n\ge0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\lt \infty$ than
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}na_n}{N}=0.
$$
In this you just need to put $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.