# Test for the convergence of the sequence $S_n =\frac1n \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

$$S_n =\frac1n \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Show the convergence of $S_n$ (the method of difference more preferably)

I just began treating sequences in school, and our teacher taught that monotone increasing sequence, bounded above and monotone decreasing sequences, bounded below converge.

and so using that theorem here..
I found the $$(n+1)_{th} term$$,
$$S_{n+1} = \frac1{n+1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

and then subtracted the (n)th term from it

What I was able to get was...
$$S_{n+1}-S_n = \frac1{(n+1)^2} - \frac{\left(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n\right)}{n(n+1)}.$$
...but then this is where I get stucked, but i'm trying to prove that the sequence > 0(i.e Converges) or < 0 (i.e diverges).

Comment: Your attempt...?

Comment: I'm not used to this..but I'll try to type that..

Comment: Sn+1 - sn, I subtracted the nth term from the n+1th term and I Got..

(N/n+1 - (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...+ 1/n))/n(n+1)

Comment: This might help you: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210681/if-a-n-to-ell-then-hat-a-n-to-ell
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930436/a-result-on-sequences

Comment: I have tried to add to your post what you wrote in a comment. I am not sure whether I understood correctly what  you meant, so please, edit it further. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: What you have done so far is fine, can you use it to show the original sequence is decreasing? It is obviously bounded below (by zero), so that's all you need. The intuition is, $S_n$ is the average of $n$ numbers, and as $n$ increases you are adding smaller and smaller numbers, so their average decreases. This is closely related to what Joanpemo told you in his answer. (And Martin as well).

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: Another question about the same limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/find-lim-n-to-infty-1-frac12-frac1n-frac1n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n})\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/find-lim-n-to-infty-1-frac12-frac1n-frac1n)

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. As an alternative to a Cesaro-like theorem, one may use the fact that $x \mapsto \dfrac1x$ is decreasing over $[1,\infty)$ to get
$$
0<1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n<1+\int_1^n\frac{dx}x=1+\log n
$$ giving
$$
0<\frac1n\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\right)<\frac1n+\frac{\log n}n.
$$

Comment: Overkill. One shouldn't need integrals in an easy sequences problem; sequences are studied much earlier than integrals.

Comment: Not necessarily -- this can also (and perhaps more naturally) seen as a series, and series are studied around the same time as integrals. Moreover, this is a *simple* proof, provided one has the basic definition of integrals and of logarithm. It may not be the most elementary or even canonical way, but it is a self-contained alternative -- why not have it written as an answer, somewhere? It does not hurt to have options.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [here](http://amath.kaist.ac.kr/pde_lab/members/JaywanChung/MAS501_2011/MAS501-2011-Homework-04-sol.pdf)  how can this be solved:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=0$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see why the implication.

Comment: @Bernard Did you read the link I post in my answer?

Comment: I know, this is *Cesáro's lemma*, but you can't use it here: the harmonic series diverge. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Bernard I think you're missing something big time, and I don't think this is widely known as Cesaro's Lemma, though it is related to Cesaro sums, certainly.. Please do read the link again, or read 4-6 lines here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: @Bernard And it has nothing to do with series, whether convergent or not.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see. $\sum\frac1k$ doesn't have a limit.

Comment: @Bernard In both links I gave it is written that $$\;\lim a_n=L\implies\lim\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=L\;$$ Can you see this?

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. Stupidly, all the time of this discussion, I was thinking *series* instead of *sequence*.

Comment: @Bernard Jeje, I know. Sometimes things are in front of my nose and I look for them down in my feet.

Answer (score 0):

If you denote $H_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$, one knows $H_n\sim_\infty\ln n$, hence $$S_n\sim_\infty \frac{\ln n}n\to 0.$$

*A more elementary proof:*
\begin{align*}&S_n =\frac1n H_n>S_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\Bigl(H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigr)\\
\iff \enspace&(n+1)H_n>nH_n+\frac n{n+1}\iff H_n>\frac n{n+1},
\end{align*}
which is true since $H_n>1>\dfrac n{n+1}$. So the sequence $(S_n)$ is decreasing and bounded from below by $0$. Apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: One doesn't need to know the $\ln n$ behavior of the harmonic series, the problem is easier than that.

Comment: @mathguy: It has the advantage of being very short…

Comment: Think of what the OP will learn from the answer.

Comment: @mathguy: OK I've added an elementary proof.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding appeals to logarithms:

Writing $H_n = 1 +\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}$, note that for $n>M$:

$$H_n=1 +\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}=1 +\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=H_M+\frac{1}{M+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$$

Now, each of the terms after $H_M$ is $<\frac{1}{M}$, whence $H_n<H_M+\frac{n-M}{M}$.

Thus, $\frac{H_n}{n}<\frac{H_M}{n}+\frac{n-M}{nM}=\frac{H_m-1}{n}+\frac{1}{M}$ for any positive integer $M$, as long as $n$ is larger than $M$.

From this, we deduce that $\limsup\frac{H_n}{n}\le\frac{1}{M}$ for all positive integers $M$, and thus that $\limsup\frac{H_n}{n}=0$.

As $\frac{H_n}{n}>0$, it is thus trivial to deduce that the sequence converges to $0$.