# How to prove $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{m = 1}^k {\frac{1}{m}} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

where $k$ is a integer. Can you give a complete proof?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: If you start with your partial proof maybe someone here will help you finish.

Comment: Have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757859/test-for-the-convergence-of-the-sequence-s-n-frac1n-left1-frac12

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: Another question about the same limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/find-lim-n-to-infty-1-frac12-frac1n-frac1n

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sum_{m=1}^{m=k}{1\over m}\leq \int_1^k{1\over x}dx=\log(k)$, thus the limit is inferior to $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}{{\log(k)}\over k}$

Comment: Thank you for response. This proof is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the help of the Cesàro mean:
Since $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac 1 m = 0$, also
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac 1 k \sum_{m=1}^k \frac 1 m = 0.$$

Comment: Some posts showing the result on Cesaro mean used in this answer: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207910/prove-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-1z-2-cdots-z-n-n-of-cesaro-means
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210681/if-a-n-to-ell-then-hat-a-n-to-ell
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248116/arithmetic-mean-of-a-sequence-converges
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930436/a-result-on-sequences